# Is it possible to show multiple form views or tree views of the same object in Openerp?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo

I need Multiple form views of the same object in my module , I created multiple forms but OpenERP shows only one form related to the object other forms are hidden . i looked in the documentation but there is no answer . if anybody know , please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have to specify the view in the definition such as search_view_id,tree_view_id,form_view_id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes it is . just make a separate action and menu for the object . for example

```
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="client_form_action">
    <field name="name">client.form.action</field>
    <field name="res_model">client</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">form</field>
</record>

<!--This action open the view we specify.-->
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="client_form_action1">
    <field name="name">client.form.action1</field>
    <field name="res_model">client</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">form</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="client_form_view_1"/>
</record>

<menuitem id="menu_id" name="Client main menu"/>
<menuitem
    id="menu_id_1"
    name="Here we don't specify the view"
    action="client_form_action" parent="menu_id"/>
<menuitem
    id="menu_id_1"
    name="Here we specify the view"
    action="client_form_action1" parent="menu_id"/>
```

with the view Id="some_thing" you can do it , the first view is by default the second one is specified , you can also show only the view you want by giving them priority. hope this will help 
Click [here](https://doc.openerp.com/5.0/developer/2_6_views_events/views/specify_view_to_use/)!

Comment: Is that possible call another model. Example:                                                  
    <field name="res_model">client</field>                                                         
   <field name="res_model">client.line</field>

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible you can create two views for same table with separate menu and action for each view.